# NSPredicate multiply values while Fetching

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have  two values yards and miles on the basis of which I want to fetch. If the user has enterd both values then I'ld like to combine both values in one as miles*1760 yards. Earlier when I was fetching only yards or miles seperately I was doing

```
if (![[optional valueForKey:@"Miles"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"miles <= %@",[optional valueForKey:@"Miles"]];
    [predicateArray addObject:predicate];
}
```

any ideas how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions described in the `NSExpression` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001190-SW23) in your predicate.  For example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"add:to:(multiply:by:(miles,1760),yards) > %@", @(5000)];
```

will select those items where the total distance (miles * 1760 + yards) is greater than 5000.

Comment: didn't knew about NSExpression :D